# testing a current_user in application_controller with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a standard current_user in application_controller like this:

```
describe ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(session[:auth_token]) if session[:auth_token]
  end
```

I'm curious as to how or whether if this should be tested. I was thinking like (this works but I'm not sure if there is a better way or whether even necessary):

```
describe 'current_user' do
  it 'should return a valid_current' do
    user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user.auth_token='abc123'
    user.save
    request.session['auth_token']='abc123'
    returned_user=controller.send(:current_user) # not sure about this
    returned_user.id.should eq(user.id)
  end
end
```

but not really sure? I'm testing our auth in other places for our api but curious (1) how or (2) whether this should be tested (even for completeness)?

thx

Comment: Why not simply, `controller.current_user`?

Comment: ok, makes sense. But does testing this even make sense? I'm surprised that things like rails tutorial don't explicitly test and curious if there is a reason. Maybe somewhat superfluous.

Comment: Certainly it makes sense.  The Rails tutorial is teaching you how Rails is expected to be used within simplified examples - it is not designed to teach best practices for developing production software.